# Analytics on cross platform app active downloads

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a cross-platform app on the Android store and the iOS store.
Marketing would like stats on app uptake, downloads, count of devices it is on, etc.

Is there a way through API or another means where i can pull the stats off the android console and app store connect and display them in a report rather than me having to log into each site every time and add the numbers together.

Thanks,

Comment: You can use App Center . It provides the above functions and you just need to add the `App Center SDK`  to your solution . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin#3-add-the-app-center-sdk-to-your-solution